# Is there a way to write a regression table from R with coeffecients, se, p, odds ratio, and CIs?

Tags: r, output, regression

I have rather robust data and would like to write my regression outputs to a "journal ready" format from R.

At the moment, I have gotten the outreg package to work in getting the coefficients, se, and p-values (code below). However, I cannot seem to find how I can also include the odds ratios or confidence intervals. Does anyone have suggestions on such a package that does this, or how I can achieve this using outreg?

Above-mentioned code for outreg table:

```
dm1.output <- list(dm1a, dm1b, dm1c, dm1d, dm1e, dm1f, dm1g, dm1h)
dm1.output2 <- as.data.frame(outreg(dm1.output, pv=T, starred = c("pv")))
```

Comment: I've used `gtsummary` to generate tabular results from regression models. It can be combined with the `gt` package which makes it highly customisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are standard models you could look at `modelsummary` [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html):

```
library(modelsummary)
models <- list("Model 1" <- glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial),
               "Model 2" <- glm(am ~ cyl, data = mtcars, family = binomial))
modelsummary(models, exponentiate = TRUE, stars = T, statistic = 'conf.int', conf_level = .95)
```

[image]

---

Or `stargazer`:

```
library(stargazer)   
model_1 <- glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)
stargazer(model_1, coef = list(exp(model_1$coefficients)), type = "text")
```

---

Or `texreg`

```
library(texreg)
model_trexreg <- texreg::extract(model_1)
screenreg(model_1, override.coef = exp(model_trexreg@coef), override.se = exp(model_trexreg@se))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stargazer` package is good for your tasks. It was designed with the goal of producing "journal ready" tables, since the developer is an academic.